# Iteration possibly skipping an element

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

I am iterating over a list of tuples in `Python`, and it seems to me that the middle element is being skipped somehow. Here is my block of code, with the goal to remove any tuples that have `None` as the second element:

```
print('List of tuples before modification: ' +str(list_of_tuples))
for refseq_tuple in list_of_tuples:
    print('tuple: ' +str(refseq_tuple))
    if refseq_tuple[1] == None:
        list_of_tuples.remove(refseq_tuple)
print('List of tuples after modification: ' +str(list_of_tuples))
```

And here is the output:

```
List of tuples before modification: [('100652761', None), ('100653343', None), ('3183', 0)]
tuple: ('100652761', None)
tuple: ('3183', 0)
List of tuples after modification: [('100653343', None), ('3183', 0)]
```

So...what is happening to the middle (2nd) element? It looks as though it isnt being iterated over at all, or it would print between the other two tuples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python)

Comment: You are modifying a list *while iterating*. The iterator index doesn't know you removed items and continues to increment and thus appears to skip items.

Comment: Also, it's generally frowned upon to use equality to check for `None`.  Use `is` instead.

Comment: Ok sorry if its a duplicate, I did try searching first. Thanks all! Looks like list comprehension is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you are modifying the list while iterating it.  However, you can accomplish what you are doing here with just a list comprehension (unless for some reason you really need to modify in place).

```
list_of_tuples = [tup for tup in list_of_tuples if tup[1] is not None]
```

Comment: Even if you need to modify in place, using a slice assignment of a list comprehension (or better yet, a generator expression) is going to be better.

Answer (score 1):

You have changed the original list. So this time the index 1 refers to `('3183', 0)`.

```
>>> alist = [('100652761', None), ('100653343', None), ('3183', 0)]
>>> [x for x in alist if not x[1] is None]
[('3183', 0)]
>>>
```